# How can I build a specific corpus - Algorithmic Instructions

Tags: algorithm, nlp, corpus

I am working on a project and I need to build a corpus of algorithmic sentences. In other words, I need a corpus that is made of sentences where each sentence is an algorithmic instruction expressed in natural language, english. Examples:

- Assign 5 to X
- Multiply the variable X by 5
- Declare a variable with the name Z

I have done some researches and I have found this Google BigQuery - Stack Overflow. I am still exploring it and I am not sure if it will help me. I am considering web crawling Stack Overflow but it looks very noisy as a source. Are not there any ready-to-use data set or API in this situation? Do you know any website full of algorithmic instructions that I can web crawl?

Any ideas are more then welcomed, please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can generate as many of them, with a set of conditions and instructions that you want to employ. Probably you should follow the generative method of random sampling between a set of "variables", "numerals" and "operators" for generating such instructions.

For example: Let's say you want to generate instructions with:

- Variables involving `x`, `y` and `z`.
- Numerals involving `5`, `6` and `7`.
- Operators involving `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`.

Then your process would go about picking an operator, picking a numeral and picking a variable and basically generating an instruction based on the operator involved. Or something on the same lines. The point is to keep doing this random sampling and generate as many instructions as you want. Also, if your set of variables and numerals is high enough, you can end up with a pretty good list of instructions.

Hope it helped.

Comment: This is a brilliant idea!! Thank you! I have tried it and it worked. Just to add on you r answer, I have added another list, a list of prepositions. Also, I did not blind-randomly generate instructions because it does not make sens, I may have too much invalid instructions. Instead, I have managed to guide the random generation as you pointed in your answer and add upon that some logic. I still have invalid instructions which is more then fine, that's the point of random! So I had to manually eliminate the invalid instructions.